# Gradle (Android Studio) won't compile 9patches

Tags: android, compiler-errors, android-studio, nine-patch

I have a problem, I cannot compile [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opiQQ.png) 9patch with Android Studio. It is from the Google Play Music application so it should work. I have made it an 9patch with the "draw9patch.bat" from the Androird SDK tools. But I only get this error: "Gradle: No marked region found along edge. - Found along top edge."

Any help would be estimated!
Thanks in advance
/Måns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the SDK tool draw9patch. That will allow you to quickly view the 9patch and add your missing sizer pixels (which the error indicates the top border sizing pixels are missing).

Comment: Yeaaaah, I don't know so much about 9patches, so here's the result: http://i.imgur.com/pgzTR1V.png
Please take a look if you want :)

Comment: Well, for a ninepatch to work, you will need to place pixels at the left and top most boundaries of the image to tell the 9patch parser where it is safe to expand the image. Essentially, draw a line at the left and top of your image using draw9patch.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html Here is more assistance if you need it